# In java, what is closest to ASP.NET MVC Master Pages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have experience with ASP.NET MVC, but for my current project I have to use java.

What view technology for java is closest to ASP.NET MVC Master Pages?

Comment: You might get more answers (eg: from people who know Java but not ASP.NET) if you explain what ASP.NET MVC Master Pages are, and exactly what it is about them that you want in Java.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532/asp-net-master-pages-equivalent-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/)

See Spring's petcare sample for example of using Tiles with Spring MVC